# Listar directorios por fecha y archivos alfabéticamente

Tags: php

Veréis, he estado un tiempo intentando ordenar mis archivos de una manera sencilla y ahora tengo el quebradero de cabeza para poder listarlos.
Os pongo un poco en situación a ver si consigo que entendáis lo que necesito hacer:

Tengo una carpeta llamada "**acabadas**" donde tengo situadas las carpetas de mis usuarios, dentro de cada carpeta tengo mucha información de ellos y una imagen o varias (1 por cada vez que se inscriben(es obligatorio que se inscriban y yo guarde su información)).

El resultado es que queda algo así:
**(puse la fecha de la creación de carpeta al lado para que se vea mejor)**

> - **acabadas**/usuario1/1.img - 19/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario1/2.qcow
> - **acabadas**/usuario2/1.img - 20/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario3/1.txt - 18/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario3/2.img
> - **acabadas**/usuario4/1.img - 21/05/2006

La cuestión es que tendría que quedar un resultado de lista como este:

> - **acabadas**/usuario4/1.img - 21/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario2/1.img - 20/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario1/1.img - 19/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario1/2.qcow
> - **acabadas**/usuario3/1.txt - 18/05/2006
> - **acabadas**/usuario3/2.img

Ahora estoy usando este código para listar todos por fecha, pero el problema es que el contenido de las carpetas también lo hace y no se me ocurre cómo modificar el sistema sin perjudicar el orden total.

```
<?php
function listarArchivos( $path ){
    $dir = opendir($path);
    $files = array();
    while ($elemento = readdir($dir)){
        if( $elemento != "." && $elemento != ".."){
            if( is_dir($path.$elemento) ){
                listarArchivos( $path.$elemento.'/' );
            }
            else{
                $files[] = $elemento;
            }
        }
    }
    #MOSTRAR LA LISTA
    $ruta=str_replace("archivos/acabadas/", "", $path);
    for($x=0; $x<count( $files ); $x++){
                                $sitio='ver_imagen/ver_imagen.php?archivo='.$ruta.$files[$x];
                                $replace = str_replace("_", " ", $files[$x]);
                                $replace = str_replace(".txt", "", $replace);
                                $replace = str_replace(".img", "", $replace);
                                $replace = str_replace(".qcow", "", $replace);
                                $replace = str_replace("- -", "-", $replace);
                                $replace = str_replace(".mp4", "", $replace);
                            echo'
                                <tr>
                                    <td>'.$replace.'</td>
                                    <td><button onclick="window.location.href=\''.$sitio.'\'">Ver informacion</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            ';
        #echo $ruta.$files[$x]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Nombre:</b></td>
        <td><b>VER:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    listarArchivos( 'archivos/acabadas/' );
    ?>
</table>
```

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda, la verdad es que estoy completamente varado con este tema y llevo algunas semanas dándole vueltas al asunto pero no consigo sacar nada. Muchas gracias!

Comment: intenta utilizando la funcion `sort` para el array bro, saludos

Comment: Deberías crear una función que primero busque todos los archivos, y no solo guardar el path al archivo, sino también la fecha ([`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filemtime.php)). Una vez que tengas todos los archivos, deberías ordenarlos ([`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php), ejemplo #3). Y por ultimo generar el `html` de la tabla con los archivos ordenados.

Comment: Gracias, @MarcosGallardo Lo he estado probando y parece ser que no funciona muy bien el (`@filetime`) no comprendo los motivos, pero me da una lista ordenada por fecha de modificación en carpeta.. Estoy usando linux y creo que usa otra de las fechas que tiene el fichero, ya que **no usa la de creación**

Comment: [Edita tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/38855/edit) y pon el código que tengas hecho hasta ahora así podemos ver como solucionar el nuevo problema que se te presenta.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo ya edite el código, pero como te comentaba la fecha parece que no la obtiene correctamente o yo no se obtenerla de manera que me lo liste. En **$cosa** me obtiene la fecha pero al incluirlo para listar me lo ornedena de forma incorrecta (el resto del código que puse más abajo no funciona muy bien)

Comment: Prueba usando [filectime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filectime.php). Para `Windows` devolverá el *tiempo de creación*, y para `Unix` el *tiempo de cambio*, que es lo mejor que puedes conseguir, ya que en `Unix` no hay *tiempo de creación* (en la mayoría de los sistemas de archivos).

Answer (score -1):

php cuenta con métodos para ordenar array. En el ejemplo que estas colocando, lo que obtienes de la estructura de directorio, es una array. Por lo que puedes ordenar, con estos métodos *`sort`*  y *`rsort`*.

Si te recomiendo que cuando conforme tu array, el value coloques sea el nombre de tu elemento. Porque ambos métodos el ordenamiento lo hacen por el value.

Ej: `$files[$elemento] = $elemento`

Nota: En lugar de usar `for` utilices `foreach`